# GDAL keeps giving me a error C++

Tags: gdal, c++

I have this code

```
  float scalingFactor = 1.0f / 2.122f;
        GDALAllRegister(); 

        const char* filename = "C:/Users/awips/Desktop/BOLTgui/BOLT/test.nc";

        GDALDataset* poDataset = (GDALDataset*)GDALOpen(filename, GA_ReadOnly);
        if (poDataset == nullptr) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to open NetCDF file: " << filename << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        int numBands = poDataset->GetRasterCount();
        std::cout << "variables " << numBands << std::endl;

        int bandIndex = 1;
        GDALRasterBand* poBand = poDataset->GetRasterBand(bandIndex);

        int width = poBand->GetXSize();
        int height = poBand->GetYSize();
        std::cout << "Width: " << width << ", Height: " << height << std::endl;

        float* buffer = new float[width * height];
        poBand->RasterIO(GF_Read, 0, 0, width, height, buffer, width, height, GDT_Float32, 0, 0);
```

but when I add this I keep getting this error

```
The procedure entry point curl_multi_poll could not be located in the dynamic link library
```

and I linked gdal correctly in Visual Studio 2022 and add the GDAL DLLs in my PATH but that still doesn't seem to resolve the error and GDAL does come with libcurl

Comment: Are you sure the DLL is the right bitedness? i.e. 32 bit DLL for 32 bit GDAL or 64 bit DLL for 64 bit GDAL.

Comment: @MichaelStimson i installed the 64 bit version i got it from here 
https://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1930-x64-gdal-3-6-4-mapserver-8-0-1.zip

Comment: Is your project building to a 64 bit target platform?

Comment: @MichaelStimson yes